# Задача о 8 ферзях, но с исключением симметрий на c++

Tags: c++

В обычной задаче о 8 ферзях просто выводится 92 решения, но мне задали сделать так, чтобы в задаче выводились только не симметричные решения, т. е:

```
Q . . . . . . .
. . . . Q . . .
. . . . . . . Q
. . . . . Q . .
. . Q . . . . .
. . . . . . Q .
. Q . . . . . .
. . . Q . . . .
Result #1
```

симметричен с по вертикали:

```
. . . . . . . Q
. . . Q . . . .
Q . . . . . . .
. . Q . . . . .
. . . . . Q . .
. Q . . . . . .
. . . . . . Q .
. . . . Q . . .
Result #92
```

и с по горизонтали:

```
. . . Q . . . .
. Q . . . . . .
. . . . . . Q .
. . Q . . . . .
. . . . . Q . .
. . . . . . . Q
. . . . Q . . .
Q . . . . . . .
Result #33
```

У меня даже теоретически нет понятия, как это реализовать, а методом проб и ошибок я не успею сдать вовремя. Очень буду рад помощи.

Так же, вот весь код с выводом всех решений:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 8; 
 
int board[SIZE][SIZE];
int results_count = 0; 
 
void showBoard()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < SIZE; ++a)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < SIZE; ++b)
        {
            cout << ((board[a][b]) ? "Q " : ". ");
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
 
bool tryQueen(int a, int b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    {
        if(board[i][b])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= a && b-i >= 0; ++i)
    {
        if(board[a-i][b-i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= a && b+i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(board[a-i][b+i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
 
void setQueen(int a) 
{
    if(a == SIZE)
    {
        showBoard();
        cout << "Result #" << ++results_count << endl << endl;
        return; 
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {

        if(tryQueen(a, i))
        {
            board[a][i] = 1;
            setQueen(a+1);
            board[a][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    return; 
}
 
int main()
{
    setQueen(0);
    
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решений немного, просто добавьте проверку, не было ли уже такого решения. Например, сразу, получив решение, добавляйте его и симметричные ему в `set`. Если что-то не добавилось — значит, симметричное решение уже было. Типа

```
if(a == SIZE)
{

    if (!solution()) return;
    showBoard();
    cout << "Result #" << ++results_count << endl << endl;
```

где проверка

```
set<int> sols;
...

bool solution()
{
    int s[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            if (board[i][j])
            {
                s[i] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int S[3]{};
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        S[0] = S[0] * SIZE + s[i];
        S[1] = S[1] * SIZE + s[SIZE - i - 1];   // Симметрия по горизонтали
        S[2] = S[2] * SIZE + SIZE - s[i] - 1;   // Симметрия по вертикали
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        // Симметричные т.о. решения не могут совпадать, проверка не нужна
        auto res = sols.insert(S[i]);
        if (res.second == false) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

***Но!!!*** Вы упомянули только две симметрии — по горизонтали и вертикали! И код написан только для них. **Но есть еще симметрия осевая и поворотная**. (Хотя осевая и так отсеивается при отсеве симметрий по горизонтали и вертикали...) Если они тоже нужны — надо внести соответствующие добавления и проверки в код. Оставлю это в качестве "задания читателю", раз вы о них не упомянули...

P.S. Вот [тут](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/Queens.cpp) я как-то игрался, интересно было получить числа расстановок для разных досок (сами расстановки не выводил), можете посмотреть.

P.P.S. Метод работает при обычном `set<int>` из VC++ (а на него намекает `#include "stdafx.h"`) до 9х9, а если взять `set<unsigned long long>`, то до 16x16.

**UPDATE**

Полное решение, расписал через вспомогательные массивы, с проверкой и записью минимального значения (см. обсуждение к комментариях).

```
bool solution()
{
    int s[8][SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            if (board[i][j])
            {
                s[0][i] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        // Обработка ВСЕХ, даже лишних :) симметрий.
        s[1][i] = SIZE-1-s[0][i];
        s[2][SIZE-1-i] = s[0][i];
        s[3][SIZE-1-i] = SIZE-1-s[0][i];
        s[4][s[0][i]] = i;
        s[5][s[0][i]] = SIZE-1-i;
        s[6][SIZE-1-s[0][i]] = i;
        s[7][SIZE-1-s[0][i]] = SIZE-1-i;
    }

    int S[8]{};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            S[i] = S[i] * SIZE + s[i][j];
        }
    }
    sort(S,S+8);
    auto res = sols.insert(S[0]);

    // Лучше эти две строки заменить на
    // auto res = sols.insert(*min_element(S,S+8));

    if (!res.second) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Вот решения:

```
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. Q . . . . . . 
. . . Q . . . . 
Result #1

Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . Q . . . . 
. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
Result #2

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . Q . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . Q . . . . . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . . Q . . . 
Result #3

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . . Q . . . . 
Result #4

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . Q . . . . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . Q . . . . . 
Result #5

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . Q . . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
Result #6

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . Q . . . . . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . Q . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . . Q . . . 
Result #7

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . . Q . . . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . Q . . . . 
Result #8

. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . Q . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
. . Q . . . . . 
Result #9

. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . Q . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
Result #10

. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
. . . Q . . . . 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
Result #11

. . Q . . . . . 
. . . . . Q . . 
. Q . . . . . . 
. . . . Q . . . 
. . . . . . . Q 
Q . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . Q . 
. . . Q . . . . 
Result #12
```

Comment: `res.second == false` -> `!res.second`.

Comment: `set<int>` -> `set<int32_t>;`. Это вообще рискованное решение, надо бы упомянуть что кодирование может незаметно превратиться в тыкву.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, первое замечание — дело вкуса, а второе — да, тут для обычного 32-битного `int`а (а в Visual С++ других не водится) хватит до размера в 9х9... Дописал.

Comment: Я придумал как без `set`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да варианты могут быть разные, конечно. Например, работая от первой строки, получим, что все отражения будут давать большее значение. Так что просто смотреть, если есть симметрия с меньшим значением, то не принимать... Ну ладно, заинтриговали, колитесь, в чем ваш вариант?

Comment: Я опоздал. Вы уже все сами придумали. Заводим на позициях порядок (вы тоже это проделали кодированием, но можно сравнивать позиции и непосредственно, скажем, лексикографически как строки из 64 бит). Когда получили очередную позицию, зеркалим её по всякому. Если оригинал меньше всех зеркал печатаем его. Иначе пропускаем. Глобальные структуры не нужны.

Comment: Но что если существуют зеркально-симметричные или центрально-симметричные позиции? Они существуют?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Нет, потому что тогда 2 ферзя оказываются на одной вертикали/горизонтали/диагонали. Вот с диагоналями пока не на 100% уверен, тут надо подумать, а с зеркальными — все точно. P.S. А если воспользоваться, что осевая симметрия — это две зеркальные? Это что-то дает?...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy С центральной симметрией. Если такое решение и существует, которое переходит в себя же — то по логике оно оказывается тем же, т.е. его код и код центральносимметричного совпадают. Нет? Для единичной зеркальной симметрии это неверно, а для центральной вроде бы проходит. Т.е. такое решение может существовать, но оно не имеет отличающегося центральносимметричного.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle - в начале статьи центрально-симметричная позиция.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну так она подтверждает мои слова — она просто переходит сама в себя, ее код и код ее же при центральной симметрии одинаковы. Так что мы ее никак 2 раза не получим. (*Отвлекаясь — люблю такие задачи... вроде все было просто, вот тебе вопрос, вот тебе ответ ("Вот тебе голова дракона — бум! — А вот тебе рука принцессы — шмяк!" :)), а потом как закопаешься...*)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Кстати, интересно в oeis посмотреть... Там на последовательность количества расстановок без учета симметрии их две: не сошлись в количестве для доски 24х24, вот и выложили оба варианта... :) Жалко, что 24! ~ 6.2e23, самому не посчитать... :)

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение, но оно не верное)
Полностью теряется 12 фундаментальное решение, то есть прям совсем. Из 92 остается 22, но из них 11 фундаментальных.

Comment: Можете объяснить смысл строчки Sort(S, S+8)?

Comment: Лучше `sort(S,S+8); auto res = sols.insert(S[0]);` заменить на `auto res = sols.insert(*min_element(S,S+8));` — словом, получить минимальный элемент массива.

Comment: Извините, что глупый такой, но я чего-то совсем не понимаю, для чего оно нужно и почему без него ничего не работает :)

Comment: Нашли решение. Рассматриваем все 8 симметрий — горизонталь, вертикаль, относительно двух диагоналей, осевая, 2 поворота. Все это разные коды размещений. Выбираем наименьший — он и будет представителем этой группы. Если он уже есть в базе — значит, какое-то из этих 8 решений уже было найдено, значит, игнорируем текущий вариант. Если нет — значит, это новое фундаментальное решение. Записываем в базу его код — минимальное из значений.

Comment: Спасибо большое! :D